# Used openmp for parallelization - the error is memory leak

Tags: c++, openmp

So the factors which can not be devided without rest by 
another int number - we can ever put an iterator to that but we 
don't know the form of prime numbers. And I think I'm still a 
student to this. I posted the code within parallelization and 
without. It's just working without ;) and i had to rewrite the 
code because of having no copy!

I think the continue replace of the break command with the flag is 
wrong and i had an invalid predicate in the for loop i found out, 
that the only thing allowed is a simple condition including the 
iteration variable - so big up if you can solve this!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "omp.h"
using namespace std;
double MAX_VAL = 999999.0;
double v2 = MAX_VAL;
double rgcd(double v1) {
#pragma omp parallel
{
int i = 0;
int flag = 1;
if((int) v1 == (int) v2) {
     v2 -= 1.0;
}
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < (int) MAX_VAL; i++) {
if(((int) v1 % (int) v2 != 0 && (int) v1 != (int) v2)) {
  v2 -= 1.0;
  if((int) v2 < 2) {
      flag = 0;
      if(flag) continue;
  }
  if((int) v1 == (int) v2) {
      v2 -= 1.0;
  }
  if((int) v1 % (int) v2 == 0) {
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i = 0; i < (int) MAX_VAL; i++) {
       if(((int) v1 % (int) v2 == 0)) {
            v1 /= v2;

           if((int) v1 < 2 || (int) v2 < 2) {
                flag = 0;
                if(flag) continue;
           }
           flag = 0;
           if(flag) continue;
       }
  }
}
 } 
}
}
 return v1;
}
double &get_val(vector<double> &vi, int ix ) {
 return vi[ix];
}
int main() {
#pragma omp parallel
{
 int i = (int) MAX_VAL;
 int ai[(int) MAX_VAL];
 for(i = (int) MAX_VAL; i >= 0; i--) {
  ai[i] = (double) i;
 }
 vector<double> vec2(ai, ai+((int)MAX_VAL));
#pragma omp parallel for
 for(i = (int) MAX_VAL; i >= 0; i--) {
  v2 = MAX_VAL;
  if(i == (int) rgcd(get_val(vec2, i)++)) {
   cout << i << endl;
  }
 }
}
 return 0;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
double MAX_VAL = 999999.0;
double v2 = MAX_VAL;
double rgcd(double v1) {
 if((int) v1 == (int) v2) {
   v2 -= 1.0;
 }
 while(((int) v1 % (int) v2 != 0 && (int) v1 != (int) v2)) {
  v2 -= 1.0;
  if((int) v2 < 2) {
   break;
  }
  if((int) v1 == (int) v2) {
   v2 -= 1.0;
  }
  if((int) v1 % (int) v2 == 0) {
   while(((int) v1 % (int) v2 == 0)) {
    v1 /= v2;

    if((int) v1 < 2 || (int) v2 < 2) {
    break;
    }
  }
  break;
}
}
 return v1;
}
double &get_val(vector<double> &vi, int ix ) {
 return vi[ix];
}
int main() {
 int i = (int) MAX_VAL;
 int ai[(int) MAX_VAL];
 for(i = (int) MAX_VAL; i >= 0; i--) {
  ai[i] = (double) i;
 }
 vector<double> vec2(ai, ai+((int)MAX_VAL));
 for(i = (int) MAX_VAL; i >= 0; i--) {
  v2 = MAX_VAL;
  if(i == (int) rgcd(get_val(vec2, i)++)) {
   cout << i << endl;
  }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

The new method works but i can not collapse the loops

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define MAX_CALC 40
int isPrime(int number);
int power(int val, int power);
int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    int p[2];
int ctr = 0;
int ctr2 = 0;
int it_m = 0;
int it_1 = 0;
int it_2 = 0;
int it_c = 0;


int index = 3;
srand(time(NULL));
double t = clock();
double s = clock();
int prime = 2;
FILE *file;
file = fopen("ly_prime.txt", "w");
//f_power(2.0, 57885161)
#pragma omp parallel for
for (it_m = 2; it_m <= 2000; it_m++) {
    ctr2 = 0;
    it_c = it_m;
    for (it_1 = it_m; it_1 >= 2; it_1--) {
        for (it_2 = it_1; it_2 >= 2; it_2--) {
            if (it_1 * it_2 - it_c == 0) {
            p[ctr % 2] = it_c;
            if (ctr >= 1 && p[ctr % 2] - p[(ctr - 1) % 2] == 2) {
                //prime[0] = (p[ctr % 2] - 1);
                prime = (p[ctr % 2] - 1);
                fprintf(stdout, "|%d _ i: %d _ %d\n", isPrime(prime),index, prime);
                index++; 
            }
            ctr++;
            }
        }
    }
}
t = clock() - t;
fprintf(file, "|%d_ %d_ %d ", prime, index - 2, ctr);

}
    return 0;
}
double f_power(double val, int exp) {
    int i = 0;
    double help = val;
    for(i = 1; i < exp; i++) {
        val *= help;
    }
    return val;
}
int isPrime(int number)
{
    int val = 0;
    int flag = 1;
    int i = 2;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=2; i < number; i++)
    {
        int leftOver=(number % i);
        if (leftOver==0)
        {
                val = 1;
                flag = 0;
                if(flag) continue;
        }
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Hey but that worked with openmp!

Comment: I'm sorry: I don't understand the question. You may need to rewrite it or ask a new one which more clearly expresses the problem.

Comment: I'll try - thank you

Comment: I think on the one side it should be about accepting initialisation of more variables in the for loop and or the impossibility to find this non recursive option of generating prime numbers - but first it is an important problem, that parallelization won't work for the break statement - that was confuising me in the first code!